# A question about "basis for a topology"

Tags: general-topology

Let $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau)$ a topological space where $\tau=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}^2\}\cup \{D_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{R}}$ such that $D_k=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,x+y<k\}$

How to prove that $B=\{D_k,k\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is a basis for $\tau$ ?

Please

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$D_k\cap D_l=D_{\min(k,l)}$ and 
$$
\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}D_\alpha=D_{\sup_{\alpha\in A}},
$$
hence it is closed for sums and finite unions.

Comment: I don't understand what i must do clearly please ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou The above does two things. At first, it checks, that $\tau$ ($D_k$ for all reals) is indeed a topology. Then, from the construction of ${\bf R}$, every real number may be obtained as a limit of increasing sequence of quotient numbers, hence $B$ generates $\tau$.

Comment: We have that $\tau$ is a topology why we must see this an other time

Comment: @Vrouvrou If we know (or believe) we needn't to check. However it looks like a nice exercise and one may be asked to prove that it is indeed a topology. (Is it really an exercise?)

Comment: i proved that is a topology i juste don't understand the question of basis and at this time i don't clearly understand

Comment: @Vrouvrou OK. Then you need only to prove that every nonempty set from $\tau$ may be obtainded as a union of sets from $B$. But every real number $x$ is equal to $\sup_{q\leq x}q$, where $q\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: so i must prove that $\emptyset=\bigcup_{k\in Q} D_k, \mathbb{R}^2=\bigcup_{k\in Q} D_k$ and for $k\in\mathbb{R},D_k=\bigcup_{k\in Q} D_k$ right, but how  ? why $x=\sup{q\leq x} q$? and where we use it ?

Comment: The empty set is always in a topology. One of constructions of real numbers defines them as such suprema. If not, it is a standard fact, that for every real $x$ there is a sequence of rational numbers increasing to $x$. Hence every $D_x$ from $\tau$ may be obtained as a sum of $D_k$'s from $B$.

Answer (score 0):

First, clearly $B'=\{D_k \in \tau |\ k\in \Bbb R\}$ is a basis for the topology $\tau$: the nonempty open sets are $D_k$ and $\Bbb R^2$, but $\Bbb R^2 \supseteq D_k,\ \forall k$.

I will prove that the topology generated by $B$ is the same that the generated by $B'$:

i) Clearly $B \subset B'$, so the topology generated by $B'$ is finer than the one generated by $B$.

ii) Now, let $(x_0,y_0)\in \Bbb R^2$. Then, exists $k \in \Bbb R$ such that $x_0+y_0 <k$, ie, $(x_0,y_0)\in D_k$. Pick any rational $q$ such that $ x_0+y_0 < q< k$, and then we have that $(x_0,y_0)\in D_q \subseteq D_k$. This means that the topology generated by $B$ is finer than the one generated by $B'$.

Therefore, $B$ and $B'$ generates the same topology.

Comment: i don't understant ".... but $D_k\subset \mathbb{R}^2, \forall k$ "?

Comment: In order to prove that a set $C$ is a basis for the given topology, you need to check that for every $U \in \tau$ and $x\in U$, exists an element $B\in C$ such that $x\in B \subset U$. Since I'm considering "almost all" open sets as a basis, I needed to check the property for the remainings.

Comment: Now that I look more in detail... you can directly prove the result using the property.

Comment: So the first step is to see that $B$ is a basis for $\tau$ but please why $\mathbb{R}^2=\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{R}} D_k $ ? thank you

Comment: First, I really want to apologize, I couldn't answer before. Let $(x_0,y_0) \in \Bbb R^2$. Then $x_0+y_0=k$, for some real $k$. Just take $j>k$, and you get $(x_0,y_0)\in D_j \subseteq \bigcup_{k\in \Bbb R} D_k$. Since the chosen point was arbitrary, it follows that $\Bbb R^2 \subseteq \bigcup_{k\in \Bbb R} D_k$. The other inclusion is obvious